# Pass image when jump from one ios apps to another?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement a functionality that transfers one image from a ios app to another.

I already know how to pass a string between apps using URL scheme, like:

```
@IBAction func openApplication() {
let urlSting = "prefix://"
if let url = NSURL(string: urlSting) {
    let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if application.canOpenURL(url) {
        application.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

and do follows on the other app's AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let newUrlHost: NSString = url.absoluteString ?? ""
    let range = newUrlHost.rangeOfString("prefix://")
    let stringPassed = newUrlHost.substringFromIndex(range.length)
    return true
}
```

but since image is a file, I am not sure how to do it. Maybe serialize it and pass as string, or put and get thru AirDrop? Is there a better solution?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are both two apps under your control?

Comment: Convert to base 64 and pass it as a string? Pretty long string though.

Comment: @Lumialxk, yes both under my control

Comment: @PmanAce, that is what I thought, so I am wondering if there is a better solution.